# Receiving an error for one section of code but not for a Similar section of code

Tags: python-3.x

I've been getting

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

For the function below when `style == "scatter"` but not when `style == "categories"` and I can't for the life of me figure out why, when to me it seems like the function is supposed to do the same thing in both places. Any thoughts about what I am doing wrong?

edit: this error is occurring on the lines `graph = graph + "\\node at (%s,%s)[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt]{};\n"(x+random.uniform(-0.5,0.5),y+random.uniform(-0.5,0.5))` and the like

```
def scatterPlotCreator(style,obs,corr):
    obs = int(obs)
    graph="""
    \\documentclass[11pt]{article}
    \\usepackage{geometry}
    \\usepackage{amsmath}
    \\usepackage{amssymb}
    \\usepackage{textpos}
    \\usepackage{setspace}
    \\usepackage{color}
    \\usepackage{tikz}
    \\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows,automata,shapes.misc,shapes.arrows,chains,matrix,positioning,scopes,decorations.pathmorphing,shadows}
    \\usepackage{graphicx} 
    \\usepackage{everypage}
    \\setlength\\TPHorizModule{1in}
    \\setlength\\TPVertModule{1in}

    \\topmargin .25 in 
    \\headheight 0in 
    \\headsep 0in 
    \\textheight 8.5in 
    \\textwidth 5.5in 
    \\oddsidemargin .5in 
    \\evensidemargin .5in 


    \\begin{document}
     \\pagestyle{empty}

    \\begin{tikzpicture}
    \\draw [very thick, ->] (0,0) -- (5,0);
    \\draw [very thick, ->] (0,0) -- (0,5);
    """

    if style == "scatter":
        if corr == "NONE":
            for o in range(obs):
                graph = graph + "\\node at (%s,%s)[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt]{};\n"(random.uniform(0,5),random.uniform(0,5))
        elif corr == "weakPos":
            for o in range(obs):
                x = random.uniform(2,3)
                y = x
                graph = graph + "\\node at (%s,%s)[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt]{};\n"(x+random.uniform(-2,2),y+random.uniform(-2,2))
        elif corr == "strongPos":
            for o in range(obs):
                x = random.uniform(0.5,4.5)
                y = x
                graph = graph + "\\node at (%s,%s)[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt]{};\n"(x+random.uniform(-0.5,0.5),y+random.uniform(-0.5,0.5))
        elif corr == "weakNeg":
            for o in range(obs):
                x = random.uniform(2,3)
                y = 5-x
                graph = graph + "\\node at (%s,%s)[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt]{};\n"(x+random.uniform(-2,2),y+random.uniform(-2,2))
        elif corr == "strongNeg":
            for o in range(obs):
                x = random.uniform(0.5,4.5)
                x = float(x)
                y = float(5-x)
                x+=random.uniform(-0.5,0.5)
                y+=random.uniform(-0.5,0.5)
                graph = graph + "\\node at (%s,%s)[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt]{};\n"(x,y)
        elif corr == "posQuad":
            for o in range(obs):
                x = random.uniform(0.5,4.5)
                y = (x-2.5)**2
                graph = graph + "\\node at (%s,%s)[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt]{};\n"(x+random.uniform(-0.5,0.5),y+random.uniform(-0.5,0.5))
        elif corr == "negQuad":
            for o in range(obs):
                x = random.uniform(0.5,4.5)
                y = 5-(x-2.5)**2
                graph = graph + "\\node at (%s,%s)[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt]{};\n"(x+random.uniform(-0.5,0.5),y+random.uniform(-0.5,0.5))
    elif style == "categories":
        categories = int(corr)
        yJump = float(3)/float(categories-1)
        if categories == 2:
            bounds = [[0.5,3.5],[1.5,4.5]]
        elif categories == 3:
            bounds = [[0.5,3],[1.25,3.75],[2,4.5]]
        elif categories == 4:
            bounds = [[0.5,2.75],[1.1,3.35],[1.7,3.95],[2.25,4.5]]
        elif categories ==5:
            bounds = [[0.5,2.5],[1,3],[1.5,3.5],[2,4],[2.5,4.5]]
        for c in range(categories):
            for o in range(obs):
                graph = graph + "\\node at (%s,%s)[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt]{};\n"%(random.uniform(bounds[c][0],bounds[c][1]),1+(yJump*c))

    graph = graph +"""
    \\end{tikzpicture}
    \\end{document}
    """

    return graph
```

Comment: All of your `graph = graph + . . .` lines end in you calling a string when you do `{};\n"(x+random.uniform`. Putting `(. . .)` after an object attempts to call it as a function. Do you mean to have a `+` in there? `{};\n" + str(x+random.uniform`

Comment: I believe it was meant to be `"..." % (...)`

Comment: Tomerikoo, Yes, you're right. I feel silly for missing that, thank you.